# Is there an equivalent to SEC EDGAR for non-US companies, especially Europe?

Tags: data, sec, edgar

For US public companies we can go on [sec.gov](https://www.sec.gov/) to find their 10-K filings etc.

Are there similar services in other countries? I'd be especially interested for in Europe, France, Germany, Italy, Switzerland etc.

Companies normally have an *investor relations* website where they publish their reports. But they all use their own presentation, nothing is standardized, nothing is properly machine readable.

I wonder, data providers such as Bloomberg, Reuters etc, do they manually transcribe the numbers from the reports into their system? Or do the companies report to them directly, in some standardized electronic form?

Answer (score 2):

Many foreign companies post thie US-style statements on Edgar.

The problem with other countries' filings is that they don't necessarily map in an obvious way to US 10Q/10K.

You may want to look at UK Companies House https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/companies-house and https://www.gov.uk/get-information-about-a-company

SEDAR is a Canadian system similar to Edgar https://www.sedar.com/homepage_en.htm

Answer (score 2):

The UK has [Companies House](https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/) and [OpenCorporates](https://opencorporates.com/) cover the whole planet but does not have much detail in some countries. The EU has a [pan-European search engine](https://e-justice.europa.eu/content_find_a_company-489-en.do). Wikipedia also has a [list of company registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_company_registers).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few websites that let you search filings for US companies: [AlphaSense](https://www.alpha-sense.com/), [AlphaResearch](https://alpharesearch.io/), [Sentieo](https://sentieo.com/). They are not goverment-backed like Edgar but they do provide filings and the ability to search through them