# Where do big data companies get data?

Tags: data

First time posting at Quantitative Finance, hope the question is well suited in this stack section.
I was wondering, where does big companies like Bloomberg or Reuters get their data?
Since now, in my application I scrape data directly from Reuters (for fundamental analysis). I'd like to bypass this problem and get data from source, if possible.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This post might help if you are asking only about public company financial data: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/54260/is-there-an-equivalent-to-sec-edgar-for-non-us-companies-especially-europe?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about US, the companies report their quarterly numbers via 10-K/Q forms available on EDGAR, e.g.

https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/0000034088/000003408821000051/xom-20210630.htm

For the sell side estimates/consensus numbers they typically get them directly from the analysts.

In both cases, you pay Bloomberg/Refinitiv/Factset for then convenience of having them collect, process and normalize the data for you.

Comment: Ok, perfect. US data comes from SEC, but europeans?

Comment: Sorry, I'm don't know much about EU reporting regulations. Perhaps, others can comment on that

Comment: Does Refinitiv get their data from filings?

Comment: @DavidYang I don't know it for a fact, but I'm pretty certain they get the actuals from filings.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there are several stock market API's from which some websites and companies browse their data. For example, IEX API or financialmodellingprep API.